# Can I use sort and uniq on an array of chef node attributes?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

We have a template that generates a bash script, that includes a list of patches to check for based on node attributes - specifically the role assigned to the node.

```
patchlist=( <%= node['oracledb']['install']['oneoff']['db_oo_apply'] rescue nil %> <%= node['oracledb']['install']['oneoff']['db_psu_num'] rescue nil %> )
```

I've snipped the actual list a bit, but you get the point.

The issue is that there are potentially duplicate entries between these attributes, so we want to sort them and get a unique list.

Also, complicating matters, not all nodes in every environment have those attributes - which is why we have the `rescue nil` sprinkled in there.

I can build the array as

```
patchlist=( <%= ( node['oracledb']['install']['oneoff']['db_oo_apply'] + ' ' + node['oracledb']['install']['oneoff']['db_psu_num'] rescue nil).split(' ').uniq.sort.join(' ') %> )
```

which works, if all the attributes have values.

But what seems to happen is that if any single attribute in the list is empty, the `rescue nil` kicks in and the entire array comes back as nil.

I think that in the first variant, the scope of the `rescue nil` is limited to the specific attribute, but in the second it applies to the entire string.

So, can I somehow build this array, have it sorted and unique, and still control for cases where individual elements in the array might be null?

Comment: How about doing the attributes logic inside a chef recipe and use ERB only for rendering the calculated variables?

Answer (score 0):

just use pure ruby for that, for instance:

```rb
irb(main):001:0> ([nil] + [2,1]).compact.uniq.sort
=> [1, 2]
```

in short, concatenate arrays into a new array, `compact` it to get a copy of the concatenated array with all `nil` elements removed, then apply `uniq` and `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to create an actual array of node attributes. In your current implementation, it is not an array, just attributes separated by space.

This is a little bit of logic overload on the template, but it should work.

Example template:

```rb
<% p_list = %W( #{node['oracledb']['install']['oneoff']['db_oo_apply']} #{node['oracledb']['install']['oneoff']['db_psu_num']} )

<% p_list_fin = p_list.uniq.sort %>

patchlist=( <% p_list_fin.each do |p| %><% next if p.nil? %><%= p %> <% end %>)
```

Of course the creation of array `p_list` of node attributes can be done from within recipe and passed in `variables` of the `template` resource as well.

Comment: The `p.nil?` check may not be required as `nil` elements of array seem to get omitted anyway.